# Excel, Count cell containing alphanumeric cells if criteria met

Tags: excel, formulas, countif

I have a column full of data as below:

```
IB1,
SRD,
IBMAN,
E4,
E 3,
SRD,
L6,
E3,
IB7,
etc...
```

I need an excel formula to count all cell containing the letters "IB" (or another specified string) and which have a number afterwards or any cells that contain just the string with nothing afterwards.

I've been trying to do something to the effect of

```
If left(cell,2) = "IB" and Right(cell,1) >= 0 then and len(cell) > 2
```

I can't use wildcards as we have entries likeIBMAN which need ot be excluded form the count.

I'm sure it possible, I'm just not good enough with formulas.

If needed I could give up the bit where I check for the cells only contianing the string.

Due to the sheet format I can't use a helper column. Excel 2007

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(0+(LEFT(A1:A10,2)="IB"),0+(ISNUMBER(0+MID(A1:A10&0,3,1))))

Comment: What do you mean by "cells only contianing the string"? Only letters? No spaces? No punctuation marks? No numbers?

Comment: XOR XL your formula works perfectly, if you post it as an answer I'll mark it up. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry! Still new to this site. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(0+(LEFT(A1:A10,2)="IB"),0+(ISNUMBER(0+MID(A1:A10&0,3,1))))
```

Comment: A minor modification incase anyone else does this and has random spaces in the cells like i do: `=SUMPRODUCT(0+(LEFT(A2:A10,2)="IB"),0+(ISNUMBER(0+MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A10," ","")&0,3,1))))`

Answer (score 0):

For the first criterion (`IB` and number afterwards):

```
=IF(AND(LEN(A1)>2,LEFT(A1,2)="IB",NOT(ISERR(VALUE(MID(A1,3,1))))),1,0)
```

For second criterion (only string with no spaces or numbers):

```
=IF(AND(ISERR(SEARCH("0",A1)),ISERR(SEARCH("1",A1)),ISERR(SEARCH("2",A1)),ISERR(SEARCH("3",A1)),ISERR(SEARCH("4",A1)),ISERR(SEARCH("5",A1)),ISERR(SEARCH("6",A1)),ISERR(SEARCH("7",A1)),ISERR(SEARCH("8",A1)),ISERR(SEARCH("9",A1)),ISERR(SEARCH(" ",A1))),1,0)
```